# Recommended DSLRs around 900$ to 1000$?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

there. I am looking for a DSLR around 900 to 1000 with which I could be getting started on photography. I am a layman and largely ignorant of anything about photography, though I don’t wanna a camera that’s way too simple and crude with merely basic functions.(if this could have been possible in this price range)
By the way I’ve checked out the Sony Xperia pro I. Is it just as good as a slr and something that you could easily go for without worrying much about it shortcomings?
Thanks in advance and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking the incorrect question.

You should be asking instead:

1. What lens(es) do you need? Focal length, aperture, zoom.
2. What kind of lighting do you need? If you need flash, is built-in flash on the camera enough? If not, do you need the possibility to remotely trigger the flash with flash off-camera?

The camera brand and sensor size mostly follow from these questions. The main situations where the performance of a camera is important, are fast action photography (in which case high fps and fast autofocus performance is important) and low-light photography (in which case a large low-noise sensor is good) and especially these two combined together (fast action low-light photography). In other cases, nearly every DSLR or mirrorless camera is fine, but not every lens is fine.

Especially the lens lineup of different camera brands differs a lot. Before investing in any system, you have the freedom to choose the system. If you have any idea what you will be photographing, you may ask about the recommendations for the specifications of the lenses here based on that.

It's also possible to choose mirrorless, so in all cases DSLR isn't the best choice. However, good mirrorless system (with few lenses, maybe a flash, plus the camera) for 900$ to 1000$ might be bit hard to find.